# Unable to generate out for id and arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform 1.0.11

I am trying to set an output of my secret manger.

main.tf:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "aws_secret" {

  for_each = { for secret in var.secrets : secret.secret_name => secret}
  name = each.value.secret_name
}
```

output.tf:

```
output "secret_arns" {
  value = tolist(aws_secretsmanager_secret.aws_secret[*].arn)
}
```

However, it is throwing me this error.

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on ../Resources/secrets/outputs.tf line 2, in output "secret_arns":
│    2:   value = tolist(aws_secretsmanager_secret. aws_secret[*].arn)
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

Is there anything that I did wrongly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `aws_secretsmanager_secret.aws_secret` is a map. So it should be:

```
output "secret_arns" {
  value = values(aws_secretsmanager_secret.aws_secret)[*].arn
}
```